# Way to use SVN pre-commit hooks to keep developers from forgetting to svn add particular newly created files

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Is there any good way to use svn pre-commit hooks etc. to keep developers from forgetting to add a file?  Specifically I would like the commit to fail if the user has a local to them unversioned file whose path/filename matches a certain regexp pattern (in this particular case rails database migrations).  User education (always run svn status & svn diff before committing), shaming, etc. has so far proven insufficient to prevent these sorts of problems from occasionally occurring,

Comment: Doesn't your continuous integration find that out within a couple of minutes and tell the user?

Comment: This is a ruby on rails project => dynamic language so there is no static compilation step. Continuous integration tests can find some of these problems eventually, but it doesn't do much good if the developer also forgets to svn add the new test that exercises the new feature etc.  Also with db migrations in particular things like ensuring proper indexing so that performance under load is acceptable etc. are very difficult to test for in fast turnaround integration testing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a [continuous integration](http://jenkins-ci.org) setup that continually builds your development branch.  Any failures are immediately sent to the user.  This does require you to have a very well developed set of test suites.  As for database migrations, it can help you in consistently testing long before your code ever reaches your end users.

That said, your best bet might simply be a pre-commit hook that aborts if there are any files in the working copy that aren't staged into the repository.

Comment: "That said, your best bet might simply be a pre-commit hook that aborts if there are any files in the working copy that aren't staged into the repository. " => Is there actually a way to do this? Other poster suggests that this information isn't sent to the server, so I presume it would have to be client side.  Have you setup a hook like that before?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-commit hooks are implemented on the server side, so no.  There are some clients, TortoiseSVN for instance,  that allow commit hooks on the client side, but this isn't standard.  You really should be doing this kind of thing by failing the build with a CI server, as Chris Kaminski suggested.